# php_haru.dll for PHP 5.3.5 MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)

Tags: windows, php

Anybody with an idea where I can get the php_haru windows binary for use with PHP 5.3.5 MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008). This is for use with apache 2.2.17 from apachelounge.com

Answer (score 1):

You can find it here -> http://code.google.com/p/pecl-win/downloads/list